# Execute JavaScript method in electron event handler

Tags: javascript, events, focus, electron

I'm trying to call a method from a class that I created inside a handler event of electron. But I cant import the file in index.js. My method is like:

```
mainWindow.on('focus', () => {
   // Here comes my import calling a method.
});
```

The error is : "MyImport is not defined."

My mission here is call a method every time when my application has the focus. The only way that I found is the event handler of electron, but I cant do anything inside this index.js.

Comment: Where is `MyImport` accessible? Does it make more sense to use `window.on('focus', ...)` from your renderer process rather than main?

Comment: For anyone trying to help you "MyImport is not defined" either.

Comment: Do you use [executeJavaScript](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback) ?